# "sql-server" type tags not defaulting to SQL-lang for the code editor (prettify)

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I know how to override the language chosen, and I believe that the chosen language is driven by the tags. I'm not asking for  So if a question is tagged C#, and I want to post a SQL Server stored procedure, I use the following before my code block, and the syntax highlighting obeys the language I've specified:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
```

My problem is: In some cases, the chosen language is incorrect (or perhaps it is `NULL`). Here is a recent example:

[Sorting results basing on a string variable content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066161/sort-results-based-on-key-values-from-comma-separated-string-variable/)

You'll notice that my answer is the only one that has proper highlighting for SQL (since I've done the above), even though the question is tagged `sql-server-2008-r2` and every answer contains SQL code. The solution, I assume, is to add a more generic tag (like `sql`) but do we really want to have to add such generic tags to all questions just to get the code editor to behave? I prefer to have questions tagged with the correct version of SQL Server, but don't think it needs to include `sql`, `sql-server` and `sql-server-2008-r2` for me to know that it's a question about SQL Server 2008 R2 and to expect that the code editor will understand I'm going to answer in SQL, not REXX.

**EDIT**

For clarification, I think that if a question is tagged `sql-server*` (and only that), the automatic choice for language should be SQL. Currently I believe that no language has been chosen because the algorithm looks for exact matches, and `sql-server-2008-r2` has not been added to the list. Why do I believe this? I just changed the question in question to `sql-server-2008` and `sql-server-2008-r2`, and SQL is still the selected language. Which means it must have matched on the former. So I guess my question is in two parts:

1. can we please add both `sql-server-2008-r2` and `sql-server-2012` to the set of tags that selects sql as the language?
2. can we consider (or tell me why we shouldn't) a regex matching as well, so that we don't encounter the same issue when SQL Server 2015 is released?

Comment: You can use [`language-all`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106514/multiple-languages-syntax-highlighted-in-the-same-question) at the top of your post instead of `language` if you are going to have multiple code blocks (such as in your post) - not an answer but might help you.

Comment: @vcsjones nice tip, I'll definitely remember that! But I find most users aren't aware of this aspect of code formatting in the first place, so a bigger concern for me is that either no language or the wrong language seems to have been selected in the example I cited.

Comment: IMO the question should be tagged with SQL, and not just to make the code highlighter happy.

Comment: @CodeInChaos do you mean instead of `sql-server-2008-r2`, or in addition to? If the OP wants to specify a certain version (which is definitely helpful for those answering the questions), how is he/she to know that it should also be tagged with something generic?

Comment: As a test, I added the `[sql]` tag to the question, and the code in  all the answers seems to be fixed (highlighted as SQL).

Comment: @ypercube I know the fix, just curious why SQL isn't picked up from a tag prefixed with SQL. Especially when it's the only tag (I know the algorithm is more complex when there are multiple tags that might have inherently different language choices).

Comment: You are right on that (how is the OP supposed to know?)

Comment: The answer is almost certainly going to be "the OP doesn't know, but now you do!"

Comment: At least [SQL] and [SQL-Server] should be there, since I assume that solutions aren't specific to that exact version of the server. I'm not familiar enough with the topic to decide with [sql-server-2008-r2] should be there too. Typically I only recommend version tags if the question is not about the current stable version of the product.

Comment: The problem is if you only tag with SQL, you get MySQL and Oracle answers. If you only tag with sql and sql-server, you absolutely do get version-related issues. Almost always a bunch of additional dialog about what version, since many answers depend heavily on features introduced in SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @CodesInChaos for SQL Server the specific version is often very important - it's not about stability but if the user asking the question doesn't know how to solve a problem, there may be much more efficient ways to do it in a newer version, or limitations in really old versions that we need to be aware of. I would argue that aside from questions about overall architecture or concepts that are better placed on dba.SE, just about every sql-server question on SO is *better* and *more answerable* if the specific version is listed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed all of the [sql-server] type tags so that they all default to SQL-lang.

It's probably not worth it to add regex matching mechanisms or prefix matching.

Comment: Thanks Robert. When SQL Server 2015 goes into beta, should I re-activate this question, start a new request, or just ping you directly? :-)